# gcm notification is not working on some devices like micromax

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Manifest code for the same is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package_name.user"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.package_name.user.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
       />
    <permission
        android:name="com.package_name.user.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
      <application
        android:name="com.package_name.user.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"

        >
   <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.package_name.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.package_name.user.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and broadcast receiver is

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    GCMConfig.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

            // Display message on the screen
            // lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");

            // Releasing wake lock
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };
```

working on all devices but not in micromax  unite a160 having android version 21
tested both c2dm and Google play services method of GCM both are working on other devices but not on micromax please suggest the solution

Comment: are you getting device token in micromax

Comment: are you getting any exception or error on that device ??

Comment: i also faced same problem, and i am getting gcm id also. still notification not comes.

Comment: yes getting the device token , no error and exception in micromax but broadcast receiver is not called as we send the notification from the server

Comment: same problem... any solution found???

Comment: not yet... @HardikAmal

Comment: same problem , Have you found the solution ?